# How to do a website preview using a subdomain?

Tags: subdomain

I'm trying to make a website preview with subdomain 
e.g. 
I've `https://www.sub.example.com` and CNAME to `https://www.sub2.example2.com`

When I do a PING command sub2.example2.com. response me, but I a navigator don't open the sub2.example2.com.

Both Domain are using a different Wildcard and I do not want to use a .htaccess

what options I have?

Comment: `ping` is not a tool to test HTTP availability. You can use `dig` to test name resolutions, and then any HTTP client such as `curl` or `wget` to test HTTP(S) exchanges.

Answer (score 0):

Don't get confused/mix things, `PING` behaves differently than `HTTP` that's why when you [`ping`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_(networking_utility)#Echo_request) you may always get a response since you are doing the requests to the same web server or load balancer.

Regarding the `HTTP` request, what could be missing is a [server block/virtual host](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) to handle your request for your defined `HOST: sub2.example2.com`.

Once you have your vhosts's defined you could test using `curl` with something like this:

```
curl -I -H 'Host: sub.example.com' your-web-server.tld
```

Check the returned headers (option `-I`) that could give you a hint.